# How to set minimum and maximum date and time in Codename One

Tags: codenameone

I have date and time pickers, both of which allow a user to select a DateTime not older than today but not longer than 6 months.

I used

```
picker.setStartDate(now.getTime());
```

and

```
picker.setEndDate(sixMonthsDate.getTime());
```

which partially works on the simulator lightweight picker by enforcing the year but not the month and day. However, doesn't work on iOS and Android.

Though I'm validating these fields, I would still love to have other dates disabled while enabling only the range specified.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: You have to use lightweight pickers to make `setStartDate` and `setEndDate` working, as explained here: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/validate-owner-badges-imageviewer-picker-range.html (in the section "Picker Rage Limits").

Comment: I'm aware of that. As explained in my question above, even using the lightweight picker still doesn't accurately set start and end dates, it only works on the year.

Comment: Ok, but you also wrote that it doesn’t work at all on Android and iOS, or did I misunderstand what you wrote? That’s why I supposed that you are not using a lightweight picker on Android and on iOS.

Comment: Not at this time. These limits are only coarsely enforced